# R: rTreating multiple values in apply

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a function that obtains multiple numbers from an API and enters it into a data frame. I want to use an apply function to hook my data frame to this function, and call it for every row exactly once. Here my reproducible example:

```
# create data frame
df = data.frame(Long=c(0.0, 0.0 , 0.0), Lat=c(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), c=c("test1", "test2", "test3")) 

# random number betweeen 1 and 10
rand1 = function(){
  sample(1:10, 1)
}

# random number betweeen 1 and 10
rand2 = function(){
  sample(100:500, 1)
}

# calls the "API" --- simplified with two random numbers coming from two functions
callAPI = function(entry){
  entry[1] = rand1()
  entry[2] = rand2()
}

# run my function
df[,1] <- apply(df, 1, callAPI)
df
```

It seems callAPI overwrites the first column with the second number (the random number obtained from rand2()). All I want to achieve here is to store a arbitrary list of numbers obtained from somewhere (simulated with rand1 and rand2) in a data frame so that I have the modified data frame at the end of the operation.

Generally, I find the use of apply extremely hard to operationalize. Is it actually bad practice and would using simple for loops be advisable?

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns only the last value. You need to return both values.

```
callAPI <- function(entry){
  output <- c(rand1(), rand2())
  return(output)
}
```

`apply(df, 1, callAPI)` will return a 2 x nrow(df) matrix but you need a nrow(df) x 2 matrix. Hence the `t()`

```
df[, 1:2] <- t(apply(df, 1, callAPI))
```